# Script to copy a column to a row on new sheet with time stamp for daily log

Tags: google-sheets

I have a column I want to copy daily to a historical log in row form with a time stamp.

so from:

A

B

C

D

to:
MMDDYYY ABCD

I've figured out this code to copy the whole column:

```
function copyDailyreport() {
  var sheetFrom = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("MSM");
  var sheetTo = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("MSM Daily Totals");
  var valuesToCopy = sheetFrom.getRange(4, 11, sheetFrom.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();
  sheetTo.getRange(1,sheetTo.getLastRow()+1,valuesToCopy.length,1).setValues(valuesToCopy);
  }
```

but I can't figure out how to get it to format to a row instead of a column-nor get the timestamp to attach to the string of data.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code which converts column to row and also add the timestamp to the row.

```
function copyDailyreport() {
var timeStamp=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MM/dd/yyyy");

var sheetFrom = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("MSM");
var sheetTo = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("MSM Daily Totals");
var valuesToCopy = sheetFrom.getRange(4, 11, sheetFrom.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();

//convert the column to a row
valuesToCopy=valuesToCopy.join('*#*');
valuesToCopy=valuesToCopy.split('*#*');

//add timestamp in the first place in the row
valuesToCopy.unshift(timeStamp)

//add the row to destination sheet
sheetTo.appendRow(valuesToCopy);

}
```

Comment: YOU ARE MY HERO! I've been scouring these forums and the internet for 2 days trying to piece an answer together.

Comment: Glad to know it helped you